# how to fix access errors in node for ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Recently I installed ubuntu and cloned my React project. whenever I run `npm run dev`, my server loads fine but the client gives the following error.

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn /home/bing/Public/TechIndia/client/node_modules/opn/xdg-open EACCES
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start "client"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/bing/.npm/_logs/2019-07-06T21_22_35_051Z-debug.log
```

I have tried all the solutions in similar questions still no fix. 
Any idea ?

Comment: [Check this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6985#issuecomment-490319841)

Comment: My react app is already installed. Like I said I cloned it from the git repo (which worked fine on windows)

Comment: please add the output of `ls -l /home/bing/Public/TechIndia/client/node_modules/opn/xdg-open` and relevant parts from `cat /home/bing/.npm/_logs/2019-07-06T21_22_35_051Z-debug.log`, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)remove node_modules and lock files

2)edit package.json so the new version of react-scripts

3)npm install

4)cd your-app

5)npm start